# how- to pass dynamic variable-between blocks in magento

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, blocks

how- to pass dynamic variable-from a parent block to childchild block.
Is there a method like this?    getChildChild(), so that I can setData .

```
$this->getChildChild('container2')->setData('pro_id',$var);
echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', false, true) ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely you can do this by loading the block and then calling either `assign` or `setData` on it.

**In PHP**

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('block_name')->setData('user', Mage::getModel('mymodule/user')->load($this->getUserId()));
```

**Or in XML**

```
<block type="mymodule/user" name="block_name">
  <action method="setUserId"><user_id>string_goes_here</user_id></action>
</block>
```

More reading:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/933/336